# python: Why listA.append('a') affects listB?

Tags: python, list

This is my code:

```
In [8]: b=dict.fromkeys([1,2,3,4], [])

In [9]: b[1].append(1)

In [10]: b[2].append(2)

In [11]: b[1]
Out[11]: [1, 2]

In [12]: b[2]
Out[12]: [1, 2]

In [13]: b
Out[13]: {1: [1, 2], 2: [1, 2], 3: [1, 2], 4: [1, 2]}
```

Whereas I would expect: {1: [1], 2: [2], 3: [], 4: []}

I guess this is maybe caused by b[X] is just a "reference", they all refer to a same list.

Then I replace [] with an int object. The result makes me more confused:

```
In [15]: b=dict.fromkeys([1,2,3,4], 1)

In [16]: b[1] += 1

In [17]: b[2] += 1

In [18]: b
Out[18]: {1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1}
```

This int object 1 isn't a referance in this case.

Then I replace [] with ['a']:

```
In [19]: b=dict.fromkeys([1,2,3,4], ['a'])

In [20]: b[1].append(1)

In [21]: b[2].append(2)

In [22]: b
Out[22]: {1: ['a', 1, 2], 2: ['a', 1, 2], 3: ['a', 1, 2], 4: ['a', 1, 2]}
```

Now ['a'] is a reference again.

Can someone tells me why, and how to get expected result "{1: [1], 2: [2], 3: [], 4: []}" in the first case.

Any useful suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because all values in the dict are actually references to the same list, `dict.fromkeys` uses the same list object and assigns it to each key. As `list.append`  is an in-place operation so all keys are affected.

```
>>> b = dict.fromkeys([1,2,3,4], [])
>>> [id(x) for x in b.values()]
[158948300, 158948300, 158948300, 158948300]
```

So, for mutable value use a dict comprehension:

```
>>> b = {k:[] for k in xrange(1, 5)}
>>> [id(x) for x in b.values()]
[158945580, 158948396, 158948108, 158946764]
```

Or as @Bakuriu suggested, `collections.defaultdict` will also work fine:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dic = defaultdict(list)
>>> dic[1].append(1)
>>> dic[2].append(2)
>>> dic
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [1], 2: [2]})
>>> dic[3]
[]
```

Comment: Or even better: use a `defaultdict` which avoids the need to use `fromkeys` altogether.

Comment: Thanks, it makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 4):

They really are all references. The difference is what you do with the references.

When you use the assignment operator `=`, you're setting the reference to a different object. (`+=` works the same).

When you use `append`, you're modifying the object without affecting the reference. Since `fromkeys` gave back multiple references to the same object, the modifications are seen in all of them simultaneously.

Comment: This conceptual explanation actually does address the OP's question, +1

Comment: Thanks, this answer also added to my understanding.