# appending values to list and adding to dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

My `binary_list` is a list of strings of "000", "001", "010",....

I am trying to add into a dictionary the number of 1's in each string of bits.
he dictionary will be created with the size of `n` for each number of 1's that appear in the string

I can't seem to append the string of bits to a list and then add it to the dictionary. When I run the code I get:

```
input: sortbits(3)

000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
{0: [], 1: [], 2: []}
```

correct output is:

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
{0: [000], 1: [001, 010, 100], 2: [011,101, 110], 3: [111]}
```

my code:

```
def sortbit(n):
    max_num = 2**n
    binary_list = []
    for x in range(0,max_num):
        stringy = []
        for a in range(n):
            stringy.append(str(x%2))
            x //= 2
        print ''.join(reversed(stringy))

        stringy_list = ''.join(reversed(stringy))
        binary_list.append(stringy_list)

    count_dict = dict.fromkeys(range(0,n+1))

    for element in binary_list:
        count = 0
        value_list = []
        for character in element:
            if character == '1':
                count += 1
        for y in count_dict:
            if y == str(count):
                value_list.append(element)
            count_dict[y] = value_list 

    print count_dict
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
def sortbit(n):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    max_val = 2**n
    for x in range(0,max_val):
       d[bin(x).count("1")].append("{0:0{1}b}".format(x,n))
    return d
```

I think at least,  this will make your binary values automagically n wide

```
>>> sortbit(3)
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {0: ['000'], 1: ['001', '010', '100'], 2: ['011', '10
1', '110'], 3: ['111']})
>>> sortbit(4)
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {0: ['0000'], 1: ['0001', '0010', '0100', '1000'], 2:
 ['0011', '0101', '0110', '1001', '1010', '1100'], 3: ['0111', '1011', '1101', '
1110'], 4: ['1111']})
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>>>strings=["000","001","010","011","100","101","110","111"]
>>>d={}
>>>for s in strings:
...     count = s.count("1")
...     if count not in d:
...             d[count]=[]
...     d[count].append(s)

>>>d
{0: ['000'], 1: ['001', '010', '100'], 2: ['011', '101', '110'], 3: ['111']}
```

Answer (score 3):

`collections.defaultdict` would be more appropriate here:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dic = defaultdict(list)
for i in xrange(8):
    bi = format(i, '03b')
    dic[bi.count('1')].append(bi)
...     
>>> dic
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {
0: ['000'],
1: ['001', '010', '100'],
2: ['011', '101', '110'],
3: ['111']})
```

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
>>> lst = ['000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110', '111']
>>> dct = {x:[] for x in xrange(max(map(len, lst))+1)}
>>> for item in lst:
...     dct[item.count('1')].append(item)
...
>>> dct
{0: ['000'], 1: ['001', '010', '100'], 2: ['011', '101', '110'], 3: ['111']}
>>>
```

All of this should be pretty straightforward except for maybe this part: `max(map(len, lst))`.  What this does is calculate the greatest length of the items in `lst`.  In this case, the greatest length is 3.  If I were to add another item to `lst` that had 4 characters (e.g. "1010"), the greatest length would be 4.

You need this to determine how many keys to place in `dct`.  The number of keys you need will always be the greatest length of the items in `lst` + 1.

Comment: Normal `dict` has a `setdefault` method, that can be used here instead of initializing a dict with empty lists.

Comment: @iCodez

This is straightforward but I'm not sure why I am getting the error

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "facebook_prob.py", line 23, in sortbit
    count_dict[element.count('1')].append(element)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
`

Comment: I don't know either.  Perhaps you have `element` defined somewhere else.  The code I gave was tested and works.

Answer (score 2):

*Edit: Corrected* `dict.getkeys` *error in generating dictionary*

When you create your dictionary, you can save time by creating lists attached to each key in the same line. This should fix your problem:

```
count_dict = {x:[] for x in range(0,n+1)}
```

You could also clean up the bottom portion in this way:

```
for element in binary_list:
    count_dict[element.count('1')].append(element)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This will generate incorrect results as `dict.fromkeys` will give each key the *same list* as its value. eg: `a = dict.fromkeys([1, 2], []); a[1].append('item')` gives you `a` as: `{1: ['item'], 2: ['item']}`

Comment: -1 Why this answer is incorrect: [python: Why listA.append('a') affects listB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165542/python-why-lista-appenda-affects-listb)

Comment: duly noted. I had never used `dict.fromkeys` before. Didn't realize it would give every key the same list.